# Como hago para crear un directorio con #?

Tags: html

en la web oficial de ubuntu, hay una cosa muy curiosa, y es, esta url www.ubuntu.com/#download

Cuando vas a este enlace se te despliega la opciones de download que hay en la barra menu de ubuntu, y cuando vas a www.ubuntu.com/download, es lo mismo pero sin el popup, es una pagina dinamica.

Me gustaria insertar esto en mi web, y no se que es ni como me puedo informar de ello.

Gracias

Comment: Tu título es confuso. Por lo visto, tú lo que quieres es solo agregar los enlaces de descarga de ubuntu en tu sitio. Puedes buscar sitios que almacenen las imágenes de instalación. Acá una fuente oficial: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que estas viendo es un marcador creado usando un vínculo HMTL. Estos vínculos se usan generalmente cuando la página es muy larga y te permiten "saltar" hacia una parte específica (identificada usando el símbolo "#") dentro de la misma página, por ejemplo:

```
<a href="#S2">Ir a la Sección 2</a>
```

Y la Sección 2 (en la misma página) estaría identificada de esta manera:

```
<h2 id="S2">Sección 2</h2>
```